# GridView with children of unknown/dynamic size

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, layout

I am trying to lay out images in a grid that is two columns wide. I was initially trying to use `GridView.count()` but I don't know the aspect ratio of these images in advance so they didn't always look good. **I don't want to use a third-party library** as has been suggested by answers of the few questions I came across similar to this one.

Hixie mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13777#issuecomment-354901602) that:

> If you're using the constructor used by [GridView.count], you can set the aspect ratio (childAspectRatio argument to GridView.count), and each cell will honor it.
>
> If you want more control, you can use the [`GridView.custom`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.custom.html) constructor to provide your own [delegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/SliverGridDelegate-class.html), at which point you get to define the [geometry](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/SliverGridLayout-class.html) of each child as you wish.

So I tried the following to test building a GridView where the child defines its height (in this case, `900`):

```
return GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  ),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        height: 900,
        color: Colors.white,
      );
    },
    childCount: 20,
  ),
);
```

I am still getting the squares the GridView ordinarily produces. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something; how do I make sure the desired size of the children is respected?

Comment: I faced this problem before. take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/aloisdeniel/81d6a5241ca9e2f82f17cf3c001444c5) example.

Comment: I faced this problem i replaced the `gridview` by `wrap widget` to solve it